# Activate plugin function every morning before begining code scenario (Ionic-Cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, cron

I am on ionic cordova on an android device (kiosk), and I have to initiate an update(function activation)  every morning in my own plugin.

I have already an idea:

My idea is when a user click to begin the scenario, the plugin is launch:

```
 date <= read("dateFile")
 if date != today
 then
    update()
    write("dateFile", TodayDate)
```

The problem is that it doesn't activate automatically every morning at 0:00 for example. And the plugin will be actived every time the customer will begin a scenario.

Ps: The plugin must to be on the plugin android platform because the update function is only available there

Do you have any better suggestions?

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: you can use Local Notifications for this.

Comment: I use my own plugin

Comment: thanks I check the local Notifications so

Answer (score 1):

thanks you every body but I found the solution.
I used the cron of npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron.

Here is the code in javascript (ionic):

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
//Every 0 seconde of the first minute of midnight (0)
var job = new CronJob('0 0 0 * * *', () => {
this.functionToExecute();
}, null, true, 'America/New_York');
job.start();
```